# Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List; Android studio 3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Unable to find method
>   'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency
>   cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>   timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network).
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping
>   all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>
> Stop `Gradle` build processes (requires restart). Your project may be
>   using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other
>   plugins in the project or the version of `Gradle` requested by the
>   project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
>   IDE and then killing all Java processes.

This is my file build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.minh.findtheshipper"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "c435c556-1f73-4ac6-9c50-11d2c08e803c",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '26.0.2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.0.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    compile 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.3.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
    compile 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try  Invalidate caches / restart.

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya. I did. But it still "Grade Sync issues".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved my problem by removing 'apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'. 
Do not remove 'classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'. It'll error everything you were BindView before.

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio 3.0
If you are using butterknife then remove this 2 lines from gradle

1) apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
2) classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'

If you are using lamda then remove this 2 lines from gradle
1) apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
2) classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'

I resolved my problem by removing this lines from gradle

Comment: Yes, I resolved my problem by remove apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife' 2) classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'. But everything error. BindView error. How you can resolved this problem? Remove butterknife or use another version?

Comment: @TrịnhMinh check my answer.